# How do you find $f(x_1, x_3)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$X_i$ is the number of times (out of 100) that a die's face has $i$ dots.

I know that $X_i\sim \text{binomial}(100, 1/6)$, so $f(x_i)={100 \choose x_i}(1/6)^{x_i}(5/6)^{100-x_i}$.

How do you find the joint probability mass function for $X_1$ and $X_3$ (the number of times you roll $1$s and $3$s, respectively? I'm unfamiliar with joint pmfs so I'm not sure how to even begin figuring this out.

Comment: Start with easy cases. What would you say is the value of $P\{X_1=53, X_3=42\}$? and how does it differ from $P\{X_1=53\}$ and $P\{Y=42\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to figure it out from the *conditional* PMF instead. First, *a priori* the distribution of $X_1$ is binomial($100$,$1/6$), as you've said. Now suppose you know the value of $X_1$ is $y$. Then you have $100-y$ remaining chances to roll a $3$. The only dependence between these two groups of rolls is that you can no longer roll a $1$ in the second group. Hence the conditional PMF of $X_3$ given $X_1$ is the PMF for binomial($100-X_1$,$1/5$).

Then we have the formula

$$p_{X_1,X_3}(x,y) = p_{X_3|X_1}(x,y) p_{X_1}(y).$$

Looking at the right side, the first term is, as a function of $x$ for each fixed $y$, the PMF of binomial($100-y$,$1/5$). The second term is the PMF of binomial($100$,$1/6$). Can you put it together from here?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, from first principles.

The favoured space is permutations of $x_1$ probability $1/6$ type-1 successes, $x_2$ probability $1/6$ type-2 successes, and $n-x_1-x_2$ probability $4/6$ failures; all of which form disjoint partitions of a single trial (they are mutually exclusive and exhaustive).

Just as the *binomial distribution*'s probability mass function is constructed by counting permutations and multiplying by the probability of obtaining so many failures and successes in a certain order, we do the same for this **multinomial distribution** to obtain the joint probability mass function:

$$f_{X_1,X_3}(x_1,x_3) = \frac{n!}{\Box!\,\Box!\,(\Box)!}
\left(\frac{\Box}{\Box}\right)^{\Box}
\left(\frac{\Box}{\Box}\right)^{\Box}
\left(\frac{\Box}{\Box}\right)^{\Box}
$$